# Opening Tor on my Mac OX says Firefox is already running

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

Just downloaded the new Tor browser bundle on my MACBOOK Pro and I get a message that reads "a copy of firefox is already running. Only one copy allowed at a time." Any suggestions for newbie, like myself?

Answer (score 3):

Although it is not a "true Linux way", you could also force kill Firefox processes through the
"System Monitor" application, which is a part of Mac OS X system

Answer (score 2):

Verify, via the terminal command `ps aux | grep firefox`, that no previous Firefox process was abnormally stopped and kept in 'ghost' status.

If it's the case, kill the process via `kill -9 <id>`  or reboot the machine and then verify again, via terminal command `ps aux`, that no Firefox process is still running.

Comment: Using SIGKILL seems a bit excessive. Maybe try SIGTERM first and use SIGKILL if that doesn't work?

Comment: I've killed the process via the command posted and still no luck i keep reciving this message: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `11839'
Kayras-MacBook-Air:~ MacBook$ killall firefox
No matching processes belonging to you were found
Kayras-MacBook-Air:~ MacBook$ what should i try next? does this mean i have a virus or my system is hacked? the firefox ID keeps changing with every command i enter.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've opened the .dmg and are trying to run the program before copying it out.

Drag 'TorBrowser' on to your desktop (or a temp folder) and try to execute it again.